# didEnterRegion triggers on speeds 50kmh+ but not lower

Tags: ios, swift, region-monitoring

I have an app in which function is called when user enters a region. It works great when I simulate it at 50kmh and higher speeds but when I set the speed to 20kmh it works every few times.

didEnterRegion should print out *"entered region"* when user enters a region. And it does when speed is over 50kmh. However it doesn't print it when speed is any lower which means the region I want to monitor is not being monitored, although I can see my region is being monitored when I print array of monitored regions.

I'd be glad if anyone knows what to do or can help in any possible way.

Comment: Whats is your `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter`

Comment: @ahmed desiredAccracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest, distanceFilter = 100

Comment: Are you trying it with simulator or actual device. For me it works on simulator.

Comment: with actual device

Comment: Does changing your accuracy and distancefilter makes any difference. Try navigation accuracy and 1m distance filter

Comment: unfortunately not